# Adding Exchange web services api to MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, mono, exchangewebservices

I am using monodevelop in ubuntu.

How do I add reference to Microsoft Exchange web services api in monodevelop.I tried following (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx#Setup)

I have downloaded the API source from github (https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/README.md) but I could not find any dll file in it.So now Is it possible to work with the library in ubuntu ? If so , how can I add it in mono ?

Comment: Microsoft Exchange web services often have REST APIs, just work with those.

Comment: You wont find a .dll in that github, you build that project to get the .dll.

Comment: When I build the file it was creating a .exe file. I had to install it in Windows and copy the dll file into ubuntu to include it. Could you explain how a dll can be created using the git folder using monodevelop ?